# Where can I find this Rabbi’s seforim?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, rabbis

I can't seem to find several of Rabbi Eliezer Berkovits’ seforim. For example T'nai Bi'N'suin u'V'Get. Does anyone know a store in NYC or which delivers to the US which has his books? Particularly the one I mentioned.

Comment: You can order the particular sefer you mention from Mossad HaRav Kook via the Internet.

Comment: [This](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Hebrew-ELIEZER-BERKOVITZ-Hahalacha/391996378708?hash=item5b44ce0e54:g:g9EAAOSwxrlaocNU) site has Berkovitz’s ‘HaHalacha - Kochah VeTafkidah’.

Comment: https://www.mosadharavkook.com/shop/

Comment: תנאי  בנישואין ובגט

Comment: @yaacov they deliver to the US?

Comment: If you want to double check, you could call them. They list the phone and store hours on the sites main page.

Comment: FYI, Mossad HaRav Kook also carries the sefer mentioned by Oliver in a new edition.

Comment: If you ask for specific page(s) [from Tnai Be’Nissuin] I can post it as an answer -don’t know how to upload images in a comment- as I have the book.

Comment: @Oliver Add the image to an answer and it will automatically generate a link. You can then copy/paste the link into a comment [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONXsp.jpg).

Comment: @Alex But if I’m adding it to an answer it’s presumably in response to a question asking for it. Wouldn’t supplying it then in a comment (here) too just be redundant? (+1 for Imgur portrayal.)

Comment: @Oliver The link is generated as soon as you click on "add picture" even if you don't post the answer. So you don't actually have to answer anything. You just have to add the image to a "dummy answer" and then you can transfer it too a comment. No redundancies then.

Comment: Aaah. Does this dummy answer need to be saved or can be deleted?